# Vuejs : Making dependent dropdown with axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I had a problem showing the dependent dropdown. It fetches the hospital, but for the specialty, it gives me an empty array with no error like this image:

[image]

I couldn't find where is my mistake it didn't show anything like this image:

[image]

This is my route:

```
// Hospital
Route::get('hospital', 'ApiController@getHospital');
// Speciality
Route::get('speciality', 'ApiController@getSpeciality');
```

My controller:

```
// Speciality
public function getSpeciality(Request $request)
{
    $hosId = $request->input('hospital_id');
    
    $data = DB::table('tr_hospital_specialists as tr')
        ->select('tr.id','hospital_id','specialist_id','specialist_name')
        ->join('mst_specialists as sp', 'tr.specialist_id', '=', 'sp.id')
        ->join('mst_hospitals as hos', 'tr.hospital_id', '=', 'hos.id')
        ->where('hospital_id', $hosId)
        ->orderBy('specialist_name','asc')
        ->get();

    if ($data) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' =>'success',
            'data'    => $data
        ], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Data not found.',
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="text-white">Hospital</label>
        <model-list-select :list="hospital"
            v-model="optHospital"
            @change="getSpeciality"
            option-value="id"
            option-text="hospital_name"
            placeholder="Choose Hospital">
        </model-list-select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="text-white">Speciality</label>
        <model-list-select :list="speciality"
            v-model="optSpeciality"
            option-value="specialist_id"
            option-text="specialist_name"
            placeholder="Choose Speciality">
        </model-list-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Try to make it work without the server, just providing the data inside the component itself. You can ask a better question then.

Comment: `$hosId = $request->input('hospital_id');` to `$hosId = $request->input('hospital');` as u r sending `hospital` as key form vuejs

Comment: @sureshvv I've tried with static data and it works

Comment: If it works with static data, problem is with server code. Use Postman or curl to identify problem. @Fenz

Comment: @sureshvv it looks like the problem is in the backend, even though the data already exists in the database [link](https://ibb.co/0FDSSDQ)

Comment: @Fenz  in postman `hospital_id` add key .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul no, the key is hospital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your controller `$hosId = $request->input('hospital_id');` to `$hosId = $request->hospital');`

```php
// Speciality
public function getSpeciality(Request $request)
{
    $hosId = $request->hospital;  // as u r sending  hospital key from axios
    
    $data = DB::table('tr_hospital_specialists as tr')
        ->select('tr.id','hospital_id','specialist_id','specialist_name')
        ->join('mst_specialists as sp', 'tr.specialist_id', '=', 'sp.id')
        ->join('mst_hospitals as hos', 'tr.hospital_id', '=', 'hos.id')
        ->where('hos.hospital_id', $hosId)
        ->orderBy('sp.specialist_name','asc')
        ->get();

    if ($data) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' =>'success',
            'data'    => $data
        ], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Data not found.',
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

and from axios u need to send

```js
axios.get('...',{params:{hospital:this.optHospital}}) // as optHospital is selected array
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the results are still the same as before

Comment: then check in controller `dd($request->all()` and check all selected data is getting ot not

Comment: however, when I try it with the static value $ hospital = 2; and do the dd, it works.

Comment: i m not understand if u try same code as i mention it should work and if not where is the error u r getting pls explain

Comment: I will confirm the api backend first, because I think the problem lies in the request

Comment: because when I check it using static request, its work

Comment: @Fenz yes please try my code there are  `$hosId = $request->input('hospital')` to `$hosId = $request->hospital`

Comment: When I send data with hospital parameters or origin parameters, then on the backend side I return the request "dd ($ request-> all ());" and the result remains [ ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220548/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-fenz).

Comment: this case has been solved, it turns out that the specialty is put on the watch, if you put it on the mount it will request when the page is loaded, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fetch specialities by hospital_id, and second thing: what if your speciality response will be catched before hostpital response? You need to bind speciality request to hospital selected option.